# Can I Choose Different Table for inner join operation?

Tags: t-sql

This is my T-SQL

```
select Id,Profile,Type ,
       case Profile 
         when 'Soft' then 'SID' 
         when 'Hard' then 'HID' 
       end as [Profile] 
from ProductDetail p1
inner join [tableA or tableB] on xxxxxxxx
```

I want join `tableA` when `Profile = Soft` and join `tableB` when `Profile = Hard`, how can I do just only using T-SQL in one batch?

Thanks

Comment: You haven't even mentioned on what columns you want to join these tables. You could join on both tables and pick whatever you want.

Comment: Would an outer join be acceptable?

Comment: I recall a similar problem, where I created a VIEW of a union between tableA and tableB. Then you put the filter logic in the WHERE clause. Not sure how efficient it is though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you can choose different tables for inner join operation, but it must be based on some condition or variable.
For Example:

```
select Id,Profile,Type ,
       case Profile 
         when 'Soft' then 'SID' 
         when 'Hard' then 'HID' 
       end as [Profile] 
       from ProductDetail p1
inner join tableA A
  on Profile='Soft'
    AND <any other Condition>

UNION 

select Id,Profile,Type ,
       case Profile 
         when 'Soft' then 'SID' 
         when 'Hard' then 'HID' 
       end as [Profile] 
       from ProductDetail p1
inner join tableB B
  on Profile='Hard'
    AND <any other Condition>
```

Comment: IF you are going to UNION the 2 data sets, you may not need the case statements.  Criteria A with SID Where Profile='Soft'  UNION Criteria B with HID Where Profile='Hard'

Comment: @RichardVivian Yes, that's true, but still for changing output column (Soft-> SID, Hard-> HID)you need `case`, although one condition check is redundant in both & can be optimized.

Comment: In both cases there is only [Profile] as the output column. In SELECT 1 the inner join on Profile='Soft' will exclude all options of the case statement "case when profile ='Hard'" . Reverse on 2nd select.

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly do it, but could achieve the same effect with outer joins

```
select Id,Profile,Type ,
   case Profile 
     when 'Soft' then 'SID' 
     when 'Hard' then 'HID' 
   end as [Profile] 
   from ProductDetail p1
   left outer join tableA ON tableA.x = p1.x AND p1.Profile = 'Soft'
   left outer join tableB ON tableB.x = p1.x AND p1.Profile = 'Hard'
   where
where
    (tableA.x IS NOT NULL and p1.Profile = 'Soft')
    or (tableB.x IS NOT NULL and p1.Profile = 'Hard')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a single statement with the same or similar case statement in your join. Below is sample code using temp tables that joins to 2 different reference tables merged into a single result set using a UNION

```
DECLARE @ProductDetail TABLE (Id INT, sProfile VARCHAR(100), StID INT, HdID INT)
DECLARE @TableA TABLE (StId INT, Field1 VARCHAR(100))
DECLARE @TableB TABLE (HdId INT, Field1 VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @ProductDetail (Id, sProfile, StID , HdID ) VALUES (1,'Soft',1,1)
INSERT INTO @ProductDetail (Id, sProfile, StID , HdID ) VALUES (2,'Hard',2,2)

INSERT INTO @TableA (StId,Field1) VALUES (1,'Soft 1')
INSERT INTO @TableA (StId,Field1) VALUES (2,'Soft 2')
INSERT INTO @TableB (HdId,Field1) VALUES (1,'Hard 1')
INSERT INTO @TableB (HdId,Field1) VALUES (2,'Hard 2')

SELECT 
    p1.Id,p1.sProfile,
    CASE 
        WHEN p1.sProfile = 'Soft' THEN StID
        WHEN p1.sProfile = 'Hard' THEN HdId
    END AS [Profile] 
    ,ReferenceTable.FieldName
FROM 
    @ProductDetail p1
INNER JOIN 
    (
    SELECT  StID    AS  id, 'Soft' AS sProfile, Field1 AS FieldName
    FROM    @TableA AS tableA

    UNION ALL

    SELECT HdID AS  id, 'Hard' AS sProfile, Field1 AS FieldName
    FROM    @TableB AS tableB
    )
    AS ReferenceTable
    ON 
    CASE 
        WHEN p1.sProfile = 'Soft' THEN StID
        WHEN p1.sProfile = 'Hard' THEN HdID
    END                                         =   ReferenceTable.Id
AND p1.sProfile = ReferenceTable.sProfile
```

This will return the following result set:

```
Id  sProfile    Profile FieldName
1   Soft    1   Soft 1
2   Hard    2   Hard 2
```